# Can Access queries match one value in a table with the field name in the other table?

Tags: ms-access

CPC is a kind of measurement, we ran different CPCs in every day and get second data. So I have a long list of CPC files and one location file. In here, I only use CPC1 in 4/27/2017 as an example (the following first jpg). Location file has the longitude and latitude of CPCs everyday of the entire experiment (the second example table in the following jpg).

Because the location only has date, ID, and long/lat, I want to link ID (CPC name) column in location file to file name (also CPC name) of every CPC files.

I am not sure how it can be done, but I guess it should be done in SQL or VBA. I hope there is a simpler way. Although I only know VBA in Excel, but if it has to be done in SQL or VBA, please get me some ideas. Thank you so much.

Example of CPC1
[image: Example of CPC1]

Example of location file
[image: Example of location file]

Comment: the picture seems duplicated, please see the first picture in the first answer below.

Comment: That's what a query is for. Join the two tables. If that is new to you, look up a guide on _Beginning with Microsoft Access_ or similar.

Comment: I know query can join tables but how about matching one value in first table with the file name in the other table? Not for common columns.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. No filenames in your attached pictures. But you will need code (VBA) to modify queries, I guess.

Comment: So you have fields for CPC2, CPC3, CPC4, CPC5, CPC6 or a table for each CPCx?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this query will accomplish:

`SELECT location.*, CPC1.* FROM CPC1 INNER JOIN CPC1.Date ON location.date WHERE location.ID = "CPC1";`

Assumes same dates are in both tables, hence the INNER JOIN.